# Adding extra malt

Tags: lager, malt, dme

I'm about to make 5 gallons of a rather light lager.  The recipe calls for 6.5 lbs DME (munton's extra light), but I could only order two 3 lb bags and a 1 lb bag.  Would it be a disaster to toss that extra half pound of DME in the boil, or would it probably work out alright?  What would the main effects be - darker, higher OG, sweeter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your yeast are in great shape and you are pitching the right amount, then there is no need for concern over it being a little sweet in the end.

An extra half pound will raise the gravity by only 4-5 points for a 5 gallon batch.
So go for it.

Comment: Would it (likely) attenuate to the correct final gravity, or would I have to adjust my expectations for both original and final?

Comment: You'd need to adjust your expectations, but we're talking maybe a point or two difference at FG.

Comment: I think you'd be hard pressed to taste the difference in FG.

Comment: Agree, you probably won't taste the difference.  But I would expect the gravity to up tick a couple points at FG.

Comment: okay, because of a whole bunch of life stuff, brew day was pushed back a *month*, but now I can firmly say - OG was 5 points higher, and my FG was actually *lower* than the recipe said to expect!